# Transparency of atomic and sub atomic particles

Tags: applied-physics

Are atomic and sub atomic particles transparent if not then aren't we able to see particles of nitrogen and oxygen in air?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. And it's important to detail where you're stuck and why, in order to attract good answers. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Transparent substances do not interact with light much. One way this can happen is that the particles are so small that they are smaller than the wavelength of light, making them bad at responding to the changing electromagnetic field (this is true for many gases). Another way is that they are neutral, so they do not feel the field (this would be true for many particles like free neutrinos, photons, or neutrons). A third way is that the energy of the light field doesn't excite the electrons in the material, since they are bound in such a way that it takes more energy to move them (this is the case for glass).

In the case of nitrogen and oxygen they form neutral molecules that are not strongly affected by light - they do absorb some infrared wavelength into internal vibrations, but light has a too high frequency to do much, and they are far smaller than visible light wavelengths. Oxygen has some absorption in the red part of the spectrum, so [it actually does look bluish if you see it as a liquid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_oxygen). There is also a bit of [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) going on, although most of that is not from nitrogen and oxygen but dust, spreading light depending on wavelength and contributing to the blue color.